# Can anyone clarify where you can specify KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST in azure AKS for other namespaces? Kube-system is correct, other namespace not

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

When deploying container in kube-system you can see the fqdn of masternode api being used.
When creating a namespace and deploy same container it is kubernetes service with internal ip for the `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` environment variable.

We cannot use `kind: PodPreset` in AKS so i don't know any other way on how to set this environment variable for new pods.
Pods are being deploying with helm in this namespace so you can't set this environment variable in a way that helm will use this in deployment.

Comment: It should be easy to augment the helm cart to support ENV override. Which chart are you using ?

Comment: Would you clarify two things in order to help us understand your need: 1 - Do your helm chart need the Master node API IP to work? or you used it just as an example? 2 - which service you need to be present as an environment variable inside the container?

Comment: It is the prom-operator helm chart. When it doesn't take KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST into account, it does have option to set apiServer to a fqdn but some pods still use the internal kubernetes service instead of the fqdn.

Comment: 1. Can you explain the usecase when you want to use fqdn instead of local service ip for kubernetes?
2. I would sugget not to change the environment variable as it might be used by internal working of k8s, however if any property like apiServer is not working in helm, raise a ticket and get it fixed there.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kubernetes Container Environment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment/#container-environment) provides several important resources to Containers, one of them is:

> - **A list of all services that were running when a Container was created is available to that Container as environment variables.** Those environment variables match the syntax of Docker links.
>
> For a service named `foo` that maps to a Container named bar, the following variables are defined:
>
> `FOO_SERVICE_HOST=0.0.0.0` (The IP Address of the service `foo`)
>
> `FOO_SERVICE_PORT=65535` (the port of the service `foo`)

- `XXX_SERVICE_PORT` is generated automatically based on the services available for the container at the moment of it's creation.

---

> *When deploying container in kube-system you can see the fqdn of masternode api being used. When creating a namespace and deploy same container it is kubernetes service with internal ip for the KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST environment variable.*

- It should work both ways because the `kubernetes.default` service is a relay agent to the master API, take a look at the description of the service:

```
$ k describe svc kubernetes
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.21.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.54.240.1:443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.54.240.1
```

- The endpoint of the `kubernetes.default` service is the master API IP, so if your deployment is not working as intended, it might have another issue under the hood.

You can also follow the instructions given in @djsly answer and open an issue on the prom-op github, vote for `podPreset` to become available on AKS or even experiment with other cloud providers (like GCP that offers a free tier so you can try out).

If you have any further questions let us know.

Answer (score 0):

PodPreset is indeed not yet supported on AKS.

I would suggest that you vote on the following feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/suggestions/35054089-support-podpreset-alpha-feature

Right now, I would say the only way would be to augment the prometheus-operator chart with support for updating the ENV on the pods you need to overwrite. Pull Requests on Charts are often accepted quite fast.

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator

or on any of the requirements defined in the chart that you think is missing the support.